# Do I need a Transit Visa for a layover in Shengen zone, I am a Cameroonian and Permanent resident of Canada

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, layovers, cameroonian-citizens

As a Cameroonian and permanent resident of Canada,  do I need a transit Visa for a layover in the Schengen zone?

Comment: Without itinarary details this cant be answered

Answer (score 3):

Citizens of Cameroon do not generally need visas for airside transit to change planes in the Schengen Area, as long as you do not need to pass through immigration.

However, if your airside transit is in France, Greece, or Spain, those countries *do* require airside transit visas from Cameroonian citizens. If your transit is in one of those countries, your Canadian permanent residence should still exempt you from requiring a visa, though.